# R - .net ticks to timestamp in R

Tags: .net, r, timestamp

Perhaps someone did the following task.
I need to convert **.net ticks** to R timestamp including milliseconds.
So the output should be smth like

> %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6

Comment: what did you try? Why did it not work? Can give an example of your input-data?

Comment: .net ticks are 100 nanosecond intervals from 0001-01-01 in UTC so perhaps something like as.POSIXct(ticks/100000, origin="0001-01-01", tz="GMT") ?

Comment: @dmitry the R timestamp doesn't have a format. Just like ticks, it's an offset from a set origin. BTW where did you get the *ticks*? .NET has DateTime and Timespan types. TIcks are used rarely

Answer (score 2):

Though this looks like a dead problem as far as the original question, here's an answer that works. The tick **635652130060000000** should be **"2015-04-21 11:36:46 GMT"**. Comments above are pretty close, but got the unit conversion wrong, you need to divide the tick by 10,000,000 to get to seconds.

```
ticks <- 635652130060000000
seconds <- ticks / 1e7
datetime <- as.POSIXct(seconds, origin='0001-01-01', tx='GMT')
```

Comment: Ticks are a number. You don't need to treat them as text or hex. Just pass the number

Comment: Yeah that's true, in my case they were stored as hex in the databases that I'm getting them from. Figured it might be helpful to others if they came across that too.

Comment: Then you had two bugs. First, ticks are never used directly, and definitely never *stored as strings*. Second, in a database date and time values are stored using the appropriate type, eg: date, datetime, datetimeoffset, time, timestamp etc. NEVER as strings, numbers, integers that have no meaning unless someone is there to explain it. You can't index such things, can't apply functions to them, can't even *read* them

Comment: I suggest you fix the database and use the appropriate types. On the .NET side use DateTime or TimeSpan and save them *without any conversion* to the database. It's trivial to write a query that accepts a DateTime-typed parameter

Comment: Hah, yeah if it wasn't proprietary software I would, completely agree that not storing datetime using the database format is wrongheaded but I can't do too much about it. Thanks for the info on ticks though.